# Maven share sources in modules with custom resources

Tags: java, maven, packing

I have a maven project which should output 3 jar files. All of them share the same sources but have different resources.

my project structure is this:

```
Project/
+-- src/main/java - sources folder
+-- src/main/resources - shared resources (some images)
+-- pom.xml
+-- ModuleA/
|   +-- src/main/java - empty folder
|   +-- src/main/resources - custom resources
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- ModuleB/
|   +-- src/main/java - 1 additional java class
|   +-- src/main/resources - custom resources
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- C & D ...
```

How to make maven generate 4 jar files with custom resources and merged java files? What if some resources override, is it possible to make custom as priority?

I've tried using

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${parent.baseDir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

in child pom.xml but it didn't work

**UPDATE 1**

So I've changed the structure to:

```
Project/
+-- src/main/java - empty
+-- src/main/resources - empty
+-- pom.xml
+-- CoreModule/
|   +-- src/main/java/ - shared sources
|   +-- src/main/resources/ - custom resources
|   |   +-- CoreText.txt
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- ModuleA/
|   +-- src/main/java - empty folder
|   +-- src/main/resources - custom resources
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- ModuleB/
|   +-- src/main/java - 1 additional java class
|   +-- src/main/resources - custom resources
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- C & D ...
```

And I've successfully used maven-shade-plugin to make ModuleA.jar and ModuleB.jar with shared sources and resources.

Now I am facing issue as maven-shade-plugin does not offer filter or replace-text tools. I need to change text in CoreText.txt according to rules in module. It is simple string replace in a file. Is there a way to filter in maven-shade-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on what you're doing with the specialized projects (ModuleA->ModuleD).

You likely want to declare "Project" as a dependency of each Module, then look into make an uberjar. This can be done with the *maven-shade-plugin*, or possibly with the assembly plugin (again, depending on what you need). There is also a onejar plugin, and if you're using Spring Boot, it can make a standalone jar.

Also, FWIW, it's generally bad practice to make your parent project ("Project" in this case) an actual project, and instead create a proper "parent POM", with the shared-Java module as a child (along with Module A->D).

Comment: Ok so I've done it with shade plugin and I've also moved Project/src to Project/CoreModule/src. Now the issue I am facing is I cannot use replacer plugin on /target/classes/CoreRes.txt because the shade plugin does not create this folder. Is it possible to access shaded resources with other plugins like replacer?

Comment: Why do you need the replacer plugin? Filter things?